# How to share TypeScript overloads across modules?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I want to reuse some overloads of a function for different implementations of this function. In my case I have two versions of an API, where the second version allows some more behavior. I have tried many things, among which the closest seems to be working with ambient function declarations (and maybe ambient modules).

My current state looks something like this:

```
// fn-overloads-v1.ts
export declare function fn(arg: 'int'): number;
export declare function fn(arg: 'string'): string;
```

```
// fn-v1.ts
export * from './fn-overloads-v1.ts';
export function fn(arg: 'int' | 'string'): number | string {
  // do something
}
```

```
// fn-overloads-v2.ts
export * from './fn-overloads-v1.ts';
export declare function fn(arg: 'bool'): bool;
```

```
// fn-v2.ts
export * from './fn-overloads-v2.ts';
export function fn(arg: 'int' | 'string' | 'bool'): number | string | bool {
  // do something
}
```

Unfortunately this does not lead to the expected result. In the following I want `a` to be of type `bool`, but it is of type `number | string | bool`.

```
import { fn } from './fn-v2';

const a = fn('bool'); // expect a to be of type bool
```

Ideas are very welcome!